# column to top html style two square text rows

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page and I want to have a table that has four or five section and this is my first section with two columns but my text on the left side I can't get to the top.  I'm tried adding padding-top: 0; adjusting the margin, aligning. I think maybe the combo on the div either adding to the sidebar or mycolumn in the table row since I want to rows in the left column.

```css
/*CSS*/

#sidebar {
  width: 750px;
}

.table-row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.mycolumn {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 15px;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  outline: none;
}

#sidebar1 {
  width: 750px;
}

.table-row2 {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.mycolumn1 {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 15px;
}

#content1 {
  /* width:100%; */
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="mycolumn" id="sidebar">
        <h1 class="promo_slogan"> Bring everyone together to build better products.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="mycolumn" id="content"><img src="file:///C:\Develop\CodeSamples\manage-landing-page-master\images\illustration-intro.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `display: flex;`instead of `display: table;`

And then set your `h1` `margin: 0;`, because the `h1` tag has default margin.

Answer (score 0):

You use container and row as classes, but you don't define it in your css.  Are you using bootstrap?

You also have padding in mycolumn.  This will add padding left, top, right, and bottom.

Also consider:

```
.mycolumn  { vertical-align: top; }
```

to force to the top.